# Best way to style a TextBox in CSS

Tags: html, class, css

I would like to hear what's the best thing to do with pure CSS.

**The Situation:**

I'm having a textbox in which i can search for specific items. Yet now i'm also having an advanced search with almost the same textbox yet the width of the advancedSearchTextbox is less than the default one.

**My Question**

What is the best way to style the textbox?

**My Solution**

I've fixed this now like this:

```
.defaultTextBox {
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.advancedSearchTextbox {
    width: 526px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

and then in the HTML it'd look something like this for the advancedSearchTextbox:

```
<input type="text" class="defaultTextBox advancedSearchTextBox" />
```

Is this the best way to do it? Or are there any other options available? As for just 1 other textbox it's do-able but what if i need more textboxes on other pages?

Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: To me your approach makes the most sense, but if you have many subsets it might get hard to maintain

Comment: I know right.. that's why i wanted to know how others do this.. but if this is the only way.. hmm :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could target all text boxes with `input[type=text]` and then explicitly define the class for the textboxes who need it.

You can code like below :

```css
input[type=text] {
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.advancedSearchTextbox {
  width: 526px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="advancedSearchTextBox" />
```

Comment: This seems to be nice and clear :) Shall i put the css of the textboxes all in one file to have better maintainability?

Comment: This makes the most sense to me. If there are many subsets I'd recommend creating a fully new class somewhere along the line for maintainability purposes as well

Comment: @Baklap4 Yes, always try to use one stylesheet if possible

Comment: Alright Thanks :) Will accept this answere in 7 minutes (: jeeej for timelimit :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
input[type=text]
{
 /*Styles*/
}
```

Define your common style attributes inside this. and for extra style you can add a class then.

Answer (score 2):

You Also wanna put some text (placeholder) in the empty input box for the

```css
.myClass {
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #f00;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #f00;
  }
  /* firefox 19+ */
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #f00;
  }
  /* ie */
  input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myClass" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name Here!">
```

user to understand what to type.

Comment: This is completely offtopic too bad i can't downvote :P

Answer (score 1):

your approach is pretty good...

```css
.myclass {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
    background-color: AliceBlue;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myclass" />
```